# Facebook app exception message error

Tags: php, facebook, oauth

I have a facebook iframe app . The first time  I try and access an internal URL it throws me the main page of my app with the following error

> "type":"OAuthException","message":"Error validating
>   access token: The session is invalid because the
>   user logged out."

However the second time I try the same URL I can access it without being redirected.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

There is some code running in your app which is trying to make a Facebook Graph API call, but it is failing because it does not have a valid access token.

Without seeing your code it's impossible to say exactly what is happening though. Remember to be very detailed in StackOverflow questions, and include code whenever possible!